# Flutter & Firebase, passwordless email auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I noticed that Firebase added passwordless email auth. I haven't been able to find a method in `firebase_auth` to do this. Is there a way to use passwordless email with `firebase_auth` today?

Cheers

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

Comment: This article explains how to implement it: https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-passwordless-authentication-a-guide-for-phone-email-login-6759252f4e

Answer (score 3):

No not really, you can either wait for the team to update the plugin, or create your own implementation and write the respective hooks for android and iOS.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth

> Note: This plugin is still under development, and some APIs might not be available yet. Feedback and Pull Requests are most welcome!